# How do you disable the .export.zip selector/extension in CQ5.5?

Tags: jsp, content-management-system, osgi, aem, day-cq

I'm attempting to ensure that all default handlers in CQ5 are known and are disabled/overridden when they are not desired.  One is stumping me: *.export.zip

I can block it using dispatcher or a servlet filter, but I'm assuming there's a way to either disable it (maybe an OSGi config I'm missing) or override it.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable the following bundles:

- Day Communique 5 Content Sync (com.day.cq.cq-content-sync)
- Day
  Communique 5 Content Sync Extensions
  (com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-content-sync)

it will remove the handler for .export.zip extensions

The extensions bundle should do the trick, but the main content sync bundle could be disabled too.

You can find these (on your local server) here:

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles/com.day.cq.cq-content-sync
http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles/com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-content-sync
```